# Problem with loadUi in PyQt6, wrong rendering

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyqt6

I'm trying to render the view through the method: uic.loadUi ("ui.ui", self), everything starts but the rendering is wrong. Below I report the code and the .ui file generated with QtDesigner.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMainWindow

from Controller import Controller


class Ui_Form(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,controller):
        self.controller = controller
        super(Ui_Form, self,).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('ui.ui',self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    controller = Controller()
    ui = Ui_Form(controller)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This is the ui.ui file:

```
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>899</width>
    <height>779</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
     <property name="currentIndex">
      <number>1</number>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="tabGeneral">
      <attribute name="title">
       <string>Tab 1</string>
      </attribute>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="addPhoto">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Add photo</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="6">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="back">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Back</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="next">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Next</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="3" colspan="3">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>324</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1" colspan="3">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="labelOfImage">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>500</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>16777176</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>TextLabel</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="tabExifInfo">
      <attribute name="title">
       <string>Tab 2</string>
      </attribute>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <widget class="QListWidget" name="listExifInfo"/>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Can you help to find why it does render like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06iN3.png)

Instead of this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHWKO.png)

Comment: Typo: change to `class Ui_Form(QWidget):`. You created a "Form" window (which is based on the simple QWidget class), so you should use it, not another class. If you want to use a QMainWindow, create that in Designer.